# What's a word/phrase to describe a personality with seemingly random or disconnected interests?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a person's personality. That person has many seemingly disconnected interests from the point of view of most onlookers, but to that individual he/she is able to draw the connection or is internally struggling to draw the connection but has a 'gut feeling' that there is a connection that bridges the many interests. Not quite 'organized chaos' because the appearance of chaos is only to the onlooker.

Comment: Maybe 'internal logic'?

Comment: Someone who can connect the dots? It is not very clear what you are asking actually. You can simplify the second sentence and give an example also.

Comment: Darn, there is a word, sort of like "polydidact", that describes a person who has many diverse skills and interests.  (Steve Allen in one such person who comes to mind.)  *But I can't think of the word!*

Comment: Eccentric come to mind = Someone who is oddly complex or irregular.

Comment: "Polymath" is the word I was trying to think of.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what question in the domain of "English language and usage" is *not* a matter of opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Your person has a very eclectic personality.

Comment: the trouble with 'eclectic' is that it emphasizes the randomness, where as what I'm trying to describe is that there is actually a method to the madness.

Answer (score -1):

The term *[synthesis](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/synthesist)* is defined as

> the process of combining objects or ideas into a complex whole (Compare *analysis*)

A *synthesist* is one who engages in that process.